# Sitefinity DB Migration without Sitefinity's Sync Module

Tags: database, data-migration, sitefinity

**Scenario:**

**Development Environment:** *Trial License for Sitefinity*

**Staging Environment:** *Purchased License from Sitefinity (but without Sync Module).*

I am working on a project. Actually I developed some code & other contents (using Sitefinity's Admin panel including Templates, Pages, Images) locally.
Now I want to Migrate/Sync the new changes to staging environment.
But Staging environment License dosen't has the facility to Sync.
I tried to use **visual studio 2013 data comparison tool**  But using this I had PageId conflict. I debugged this issue found that some ID's ware different on both Databases, sply for **Ownr** field.

I want to know if I change this Field value & copy new records in Staging DB will solve my problem.

Or there's any other way to integrate my changes to Staging Database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't made changes to the staging environment, you could take a backup of your local database and reinstate it over the staging database. Its sounds like all your changes (templates, pages and images) are going to be stored in the database by default. Any configuration changes you might have made locally are going to be stored in the App_Data/Sitefinity/Configuration folder, so you might want to publish your local project and use a tool like Beyond Compare to view those differences and migrate those over to staging as well.

I agree, without the purchase of the Site Sync license keeping different Sitefinity environments in sync is a major headache. If I'm doing development work on a Sitefinity site that is in production, I end up having to recreate the page and db changes on that server once the changes are ready for the live environment.

Comment: well actually, I tried it, but I developed the code using trial license (Sitefinity), But I can't change Client's License. And that is creating issues.

Comment: Is the client site and your site on the same version of Sitefinity? If the versions are the same you should be able to overwrite.

Comment: yes the versions are same but we were not able to overwrite as there were licensing keys which were stored in sitefinity tables and if we overwrite our code files with trial license with client license in the db , it was resulting in a conflict and in the end , we had to re-create all pages in client license project from scratch.

Comment: The license key is stored in the Sitefinity.lic file that is in the App_Data/Sitefinity directory.  As long as you didn't overwrite that file, you should be ok as far as licensing goes.  Obviously that doesn't help with the database issue specifically, but it should at least stop the licencing from being changed when you publish.